# How to grant read-write access to a user within the whole database cluster?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role, data

I got a database cluster with 1300 databases. I created a role and a user and granted access using the command  `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser`, so `myuser` is able to run queries in one particular database.  When I connect to a different database with `myuser` and run `select * from person`, I get "permission denied", so I need to connect as admin to that database and run `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser` again,  then login as `myuser` and  then I'm able to run `select * from person`.

I have 1300 databases in the cluster, as I said. Is there any command which grants read and write privileges in the whole cluster for `myuser`?
Please note: `myuser` should not be a superuser.

I tried:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO service;`

\t

SELECT '\connect ' || datname || '; ' ||E'\n'|| 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to myuser;' FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;
```

but these commands only work in the database where I run them, and for all different databases I have to run them again like 1000 times.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to at least PostgreSQL v14 and run

```
GRANT pg_read_all_data, pg_write_all_data TO myuser;
```